# Is this correct way to find this limit?

Tags: solution-verification

I have to find limit of the following

$(a^\sqrt{x}-a^\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})/(a^\sqrt{x}+a^\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})\;$ as $x$ tends to $0$.

My attempt: $(a^\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}-1)/(a^\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}+1)$

Now let $\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}=t$
Then as $x$ tends to 0 $t$  tends negative infinity. So my limit is -1. Is this answer correct? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good but $a^{t} \to 0$ if $ a>1$, it tends to $1$ if $0<a<1$

The limit is $1$ if $0 <a<1$ and $-1$ if $a > 1$. For $a=1$ it is clearly $0$.

[We are taking limit as $ x \to 0$ through positive values of $x$ since the function is not defined for $x<0$].

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that it is given a>1 and x>1.

Comment: How can $x\to 0$ if $x>1$?  @NatashaJ

Comment: It is given in the book that way! I thought about it too!

Comment: How will limit tend to 1 if $0<a<1$? Won't it tend to infinity?

Comment: @NatashaJ $a^{t} \to \infty$ but $\frac {a^{t}-1}{a^{t}+1} \to 1$.

Comment: Ok! I got it. Thank you so much!!